# Build Solr with custom version string

Tags: ant, solr, solr4

I've modified a patch for Solr 4.10.4, I have it working, and I can successfully compile and package it. I now want to customize the version to indicate that it's not vanilla Solr.

I've looked though the ant build configurations, but I haven't been able to find the actual version setting used. `solr-4.10.4/build.xml` has:

```xml
<property name="version" value="4.10.1-SNAPSHOT"/>
```

However, Solr is compiled as `4.10.4-SNAPSHOT` so that's not the actual version used. Nothing stands out in `solr-4.10.4/solr/build.xml`.

How do you customize Solr's version string when building with *ant*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version string is specified in Lucene's `solr-4.10.4/lucene/common-build.xml`. In it you will find four version strings:

```xml
<!-- The base version of the next release (including bugfix number, e.g., x.y.z+): -->
<property name="version.base" value="4.10.4"/>

...

<!--TODO: remove once Jenkins jobs are updated:--><property name="dev.version.suffix" value="SNAPSHOT"/>

<!-- Suffix of the version, by default SNAPSHOT: -->
<property name="version.suffix" value="${dev.version.suffix}"/>
<property name="version" value="${version.base}-${version.suffix}"/>
```

The *version.base* and *version* properties should really be left alone because you most likely want to change *version.suffix* to indicate a patched or modified version. Even though *version.suffix* uses *dev.version.suffix*, it is marked to be removed so it would be safer to change *version.suffix* directly.

To indicate Solr was modified, you could use `<your-name>1` for *version.suffix* to indicate this is the first revision of your modified version. E.g.,

```
<property name="version.suffix" value="cpburnz1"/>
```

This will change the resulting version to be `4.10.4-cpburnz1` instead of `4.10.4-SNAPSHOT`.

Alternatively, you can specify the *version.suffix* at the command line for *ant* by using the `-D` argument. If this is done, it must be used with all commands. E.g.,

```bash
ant -Dversion.suffix=cpburnz1 compile
cd solr/ && ant -Dversion.suffix=cpburnz1 package
```